# Merge multiple tables in SSIS or SQL command

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I'm facing a problem with fetching data from multiple sources. It would be great if you can provide your ideas to design the SQL query.
I have to take data from two tables and `INSERT` it into a third table.

**INPUT**

```
TABLE 1
- TaskOrderNumer
- MemberID

TABLE 2
- ReferenceID
- MemberID
```

**OUTPUT**

```
TABLE 3
- TaskRefID
- PatID
```

My input table has `TaskOrderNumber` and `MemberID`. Right now I'm joining `TABLE1` and `TABLE2` based on `MemberID`. I'm getting the corresponding `ReferenceID` from `TABLE2` and mapping it into `PatID` of `TABLE3`. The `TaskOrder` Number in `TABLE1`= `TaskRefID` in `TABLE3`.

I'm currently doing this using SSIS components. I want to make sure that the correct data is MERGED. I'm not able to map the `TaskOrderNumber` to `TaskRefID`. Can you please help me design the solution.

[image]

Comment: Try with a derived column with the same name (TaskRefID).

Comment: @JacobH - Do you mean instead of Merge? Where should I use Derived column?

Comment: Why are you not able to map TaskOrderNumber to TaskRefID?   What happens when you try?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply query the information you are trying to display. I am not sure I would even bother with SSIS here unless your sources aren't SQL.

```
select t1.TaskOrderID as TaskRefID
   ,t2.ReferenceID as PatID
into Table3 --Added this as edit.
from Table1 t1
join Table2 t2 on t1.MemberID=t2.MemberID
```